# How to connect a sqlite database in remote host

Tags: php, sqlite

i have been in a problem to connect to a sqlite database in remote host. I have already gone through alot of research on this, it seems not possible, but using rest api (building web services) can solve this problem. I can't use web services to interact with DB for my application.

Additional details,

is it possible to use path as `http://192.168.0.6/computer_a/computer_a.sqlite ??` I have tried this but not working

my code

```
$db = new SQLite3($comAdb) or die('Unable to open database');
```

$comAdb -> `http://192.168.0.6/computer_a/computer_a.sqlite`

Please help

Thanks

Comment: seems it will attach databases placed on a application folder not on sqlite file that is on same local area network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to give a path on a file system.

You could use `cURL` to download the database, save it locally and then access it.

Comment: the problem is like, if im updating the data into ip address 192.168.0.6, it should also connect to ip addr 192.168.0.7 and update the same

Comment: The you'd need to add a mechanism to allow you to write the file back after editing, and deal with race conditions. If you want to do database work over a network, then you should look at using a networked RMDS instead of one designed to be treated as a file.

Comment: whether it is possible to connect like this : new sqlite3('file:\\192.168.0.6\location\file.sqlite')

Comment: No, it isn't. You could use something like NFS to mount the remote file system on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a file system mapping to the remote directory, where the second database resides?
Then you can just use  [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)