# Configure a remote sqlite3 database on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I programmed an application using rails and I can deploy it on a single machine. It uses a sqlite3 database that is created in the local machine.

Now I need to put that db on another machine, but I have no idea how. I installed a rails environment on the other machine and sqlite3. I configured the database.yml file this way:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  host: 172.**.**.**
  pool: 5
  timeout: 10000
  username: username
  password: password
```

However nothing happens. Do I need to configure something on the other machine? Am I missing something? Sorry if I seem ignorant, is the first time I do something like this.

Comment: Can you SSH to the db machine?

Comment: Yes I can without problem.

Comment: Sqlite is a file base DBMS, without service on network. But you may learn from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571277/how-to-connect-a-sqlite-database-in-remote-host

Comment: Do you run the "rake db:migrate" command? If yes, will see any tables in the db machine?

Comment: Yes. It does nothing, or it tries to do it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, no, you cannot, and it's actually discouraged in [SQLite own manual](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html):

> If you have many client programs accessing a common database over a
>   network, you should consider using a client/server database engine
>   instead of SQLite.

You can take a look at various solutions built around SQLite to solve this problem [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork).

However, a much better solution would be to switch to another RDBMS such as MySQL or Postgresql. It should not impact your app much (as ActiveRecord does a nice job of isolating you of the DB specific instruction).